# Google Column Graph Single Date and value showing as multiple adjucent bars

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Data Table structure is as follows

```
    {
  "cols": [
    {
      "id": "",
      "label": "Date",
      "pattern": "",
      "type": "date"
    },
    {
      "id": "Col1",
      "label": "Col1 Label",
      "pattern": "",
      "type": "number"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "c": [
        {
          "v": "Date(2017, 5, 27)"
        },
        {
          "v": 213
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

H Axis options

```
        hAxis: {
      slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 35,
      titleTextStyle: {bold: false, fontSize: 11, color: '#610B38'},
      textStyle: {
        bold: true, fontSize: 8, color: '#4d4d4d'
      },
      maxAlternation: 1,
      showTextEvery: 1,
      viewWindowMode : 'maximized',
      gridlines:
      {
        count: 31
      },
       bar: { groupWidth: 40 }

    }
```

But in the column graph it is displaying multiple adjacent bars looks like time instead of a single date

[image]

This issue happening only for single date.

I want to display the column chart as single bar instead of big rectangle.

Any feedback appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recommend setting the `min` / `max` values on the `viewWindow` explicitly

keeping within a day should prevent "column overflow"

```
  viewWindow: {
    min: new Date(dateRange.min.getTime() - oneDay),
    max: new Date(dateRange.max.getTime() + oneDay)
  }
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    $(window).on('resize', drawChart);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols": [
      {
        "id": "",
        "label": "Date",
        "pattern": "",
        "type": "date"
      },
      {
        "id": "Col1",
        "label": "Col1 Label",
        "pattern": "",
        "type": "number"
      }
    ],
    "rows": [
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "Date(2017, 5, 27)"
          },
          {
            "v": 213
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  });

  var oneDay = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  var dateRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart($('.chart')[0]);
  chart.draw(data, {
    hAxis: {
      slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle: 35,
      textStyle: {
        bold: true,
        fontSize: 8,
        color: '#4d4d4d'
      },
      viewWindow: {
        min: new Date(dateRange.min.getTime() - oneDay),
        max: new Date(dateRange.max.getTime() + oneDay)
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="chart"></div>
```

---

not much you can do for the actual size of the column
the release notes from [February, 23 2016](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#february-23-2016) mention...

> Added options to specify `bar.width`, `bar.gap`, `bar.group.width` (was `bar.groupWidth`) and `bar.group.gap`.

but **none have ever worked** for me when only one row of data...

Comment: This really helps.
Now the issue is the +/- date
I want to display only the single day and don't want to show -1 or +1 days.
If I removed + & - oneDay then X axis not showing the date label at all.
Any idea how to resolve that.
Bar size still an issue I need to fix after this

Comment: try using `halfDay` instead of `oneDay` --> `(1000 * 60 * 60 * 12)` -- or use a discrete axis where date value is a string...