# How do I include a date column in a google visualisation datatable column taken from a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, date, charts, google-visualization

I have a Google sheet that look like this:

```
   Date     Sales
31/03/2017  1000
30/06/2017  2000
30/09/2017  1500
31/12/2017  2500
31/03/2018  4000
```

If I import this using .arrayToDataTable in Google charts and set the type of column 0 to 'date' or 'string' -  it doesn't like it, because the date is only a formatted number i.e 43190 = 31/3/2018.  so the type has to be 'number' which then only displays the underlying number on the chart and not the date

I can loop through each of the row values and I've tried changing them with this

```
function formatDate(date) {
   var d = new Date((date - 25569)*86400*1000),
   locale = "en-us",
   month = d.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "short" });
   var formattedDate = d.getDay() + "/" + month + "/" + d.getFullYear();
   return formattedDate
}
```

this converts the number to a date string - so with an input of, say,  43190 it returns 31/Mar/2018 but I still can't change the column type to 'date'

I could output the dates as strings but they don't sort in chronological order but alphabetical - I want them chronological.

can anybody show me where I'm going wrong?

EDIT:

If I change the function to

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var d = new Date((date - 25569)*86400*1000)
  return d
}
```

this now sets the column values to the full date object

but I get an error a saying "Value Sun Jun 30 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time) does not match type number in column index 0"

Now this must be referring to the datatable column zero, which in the original table, is a date number.  I've tried adding:

```
data.setColumnProperty(0, 'type' , 'date')
```

but seem to get the same error.

perhaps I'm not changing the type at the correct point in the code.

to clarify:  I'm getting the original values from a range in the google sheet then converting that range to a datatable using .arrayToDataTable.  So I'm not sure I can define the column type at the point of making the datatable hence the separate attempt with:

```
data.setColumnProperty(0, 'type' , 'date')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply the complete date object in the date-type column.

Good documentation about dates can be found here 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#axesgridlinesticks

An example of dates and sales could be

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');

        data.addRows([
          [new Date(2015, 0, 1), 5],  [new Date(2015, 0, 2), 7],  [new Date(2015, 0, 3), 3],
          [new Date(2015, 0, 4), 1],  [new Date(2015, 0, 5), 3],  [new Date(2015, 0, 6), 4],
          [new Date(2015, 0, 7), 3],  [new Date(2015, 0, 8), 4],  [new Date(2015, 0, 9), 2],
          [new Date(2015, 0, 10), 5], [new Date(2015, 0, 11), 8], [new Date(2015, 0, 12), 6],
          [new Date(2015, 0, 13), 3], [new Date(2015, 0, 14), 3], [new Date(2015, 0, 15), 5],
          [new Date(2015, 0, 16), 7], [new Date(2015, 0, 17), 6], [new Date(2015, 0, 18), 6],
          [new Date(2015, 0, 19), 3], [new Date(2015, 0, 20), 1], [new Date(2015, 0, 21), 2],
          [new Date(2015, 0, 22), 4], [new Date(2015, 0, 23), 6], [new Date(2015, 0, 24), 5],
          [new Date(2015, 0, 25), 9], [new Date(2015, 0, 26), 4], [new Date(2015, 0, 27), 9],
          [new Date(2015, 0, 28), 8], [new Date(2015, 0, 29), 6], [new Date(2015, 0, 30), 4],
          [new Date(2015, 0, 31), 6], [new Date(2015, 1, 1), 7],  [new Date(2015, 1, 2), 9]
        ]);
```

You could than add the following to options to format your date

```
hAxis: {
    format: 'MM/dd/yyyy'
}
```

Comment: Oh I'm nearly there....   I added into the array source  {label: 'Period', type: 'date'}  and I've now got it to recognise the dates.  so I will try and format them in the filter and the axis now

Comment: You are using the .arrayToDataTable to convert to a datatable. In my example i create a dataTable using new google.visualization.DataTable(); and then adding columns with types, and rows to it. Also i cant find the function setColumnProperty in the documentation. What type of chart are you creating ?

Comment: thanks for your reply.  It's a column chart.   The .setColumnProperty is here https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference within the DataTable Class. but it's OK I've added it directly to the source array in my Apps Script. I've formatted the axis just can't format the category filter at the minute and plotting time columns on the chart is bizarre. it plots on time point across multiple years with the actual time point in the centre of a massive column.  anyhows...I'll get there

Comment: as for a _massive column_, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44808292/5090771)...

Comment: You can set the hAxis.maxValue and hAxis.minValue to define a range in your horizontal axis